# Is it possible to give persist after time for rabbitMq messages?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

While publishing messages to any of the rabbitMq queues we can make them persistent by passing the options object `{persistent: true}`, I was wondering if there is an option available which will instruct the messaging system to persist this message only if it is not consumed in some specified period that's how it could significantly improve the performance of the system.

I'm using nodeJs for making both consumer and producer and for that I'm using `amqplib` library

Comment: What you want to achieve exactly? If a message not consumed for a while do you want to remove it from the queue?

Comment: I want that if the message is consumed in a specified time lets say within 5 minutes then don't write it on the disk but if it takes is not consumed even after 5 minutes then only write it to disk

Comment: Actually, I have made a batch consumption system in which my consumer waits for 1000 messages to pile up and once 1000 messages are ready it write them at once to mongoDB. But since all those messages are also durable messages it happens that they are also being written to disk before I push them to mongo. Which is significantly consuming my IO and reducing the performance

Answer (score 0):

The `persistent` option is set when a message is published, so there is no way to do this within RabbitMQ aside from developing your own custom plugin. You will have to write your own process to "move" messages to a persistent state.

Answer (score 0):

Following the previous answer, you could Set a TTL for the messages and then send them to a Dead Letter Queue, and any message there you can read those messages and persist them if needed